# Can we install Microsoft SQL ODBC driver version 11 for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have been trying to connect to a DB on SQL Server 2012 via R/ Python on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have downloaded the ODBC driver version 17 for Ubuntu and it does not let me connect to the DB server. I tried installing ODBC driver version 11 but it has no instructions for Ubuntu 20.04, can someone help me here?